# Where can I see the extra info I bundle with job in Azure Mobile Engagement

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-engagement

If I bundle extra info

```
            EngagementAgent engagementAgent = EngagementAgent.getInstance(mContext);
            Bundle signInExtras = new Bundle();
            signInExtras.putString("username", mEmail);
            engagementAgent.startJob("sign_in", signInExtras);
```

Where can I see this info in the Engagement portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portal cannot display this data, but it can be used to **match segments**.

Jobs can also be exported using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mobile-engagement/mobile-engagement-api-export-overview.